# Как добавить Items в treectrl

Tags: python, wxpython

Добрый день. Как добавить элемент второго уровня в дерево.

```
self.tree_ctrl_1.AddRoot('1')
```

Работает, а когда пишу:

```
self.tree_ctrl_1.AppendItem(root,'2')
```

То ничего не происходит. Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Функция AddRoot() возвращает TreeItemId (смотрим доку). А AppendItem() требует это TreeItemId в качестве параметра. По сути, в вызове "self.tree_ctrl_1.AppendItem(root,'2')" root - неинициализированная переменная. Всего-то исправлений 
root = self.tree_ctrl_1.AddRoot('1')
self.tree_ctrl_1.AppendItem(root,'2')

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующую конструкцию. У меня так работает.

```
self.treeCtrl1.AppendItem(self.treeCtrl1.GetRootItem(),'name')
```

Если не помогло - код в студию.

Comment: Спасибо.
Все работает.